# How to fix Error Modules Not found on Node/npm/pm2 in Linux Server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, vue.js, node-modules

Hello Stackoverflow people!

I have a web app hosted on a Linux server running with pm2 installed. I encountered an error in the log which I haven't seen before. The error is as follow:

```
1|joo-api  |     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
1|joo-api  |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
1|joo-api  |     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
1|joo-api  |     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
1|joo-api  | { Error: Cannot find module '/srv/joo-api'
1|joo-api  |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
1|joo-api  |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
1|joo-api  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainerFork.js:27:21)
1|joo-api  |     at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
1|joo-api  |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
1|joo-api  |     at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
1|joo-api  |     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
1|joo-api  |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
1|joo-api  |     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
1|joo-api  |     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }

/home/appadmin/.pm2/logs/joo-app-error.log last 15 lines:
0|joo-app  |     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
0|joo-app  |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
0|joo-app  |     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
0|joo-app  |     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
0|joo-app  | { Error: Cannot find module '/srv/joo-app'
0|joo-app  |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
0|joo-app  |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
0|joo-app  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainerFork.js:27:21)
0|joo-app  |     at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
0|joo-app  |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
0|joo-app  |     at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
0|joo-app  |     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
0|joo-app  |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
0|joo-app  |     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
0|joo-app  |     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
```

and now pm2 status is **errored**

I tried pm2 kill, restart, start, node update and pm2 update. All did not work. Anyone have any idea what causing it?

Comment: did you install packages with `npm install` with `package.json`?

Comment: I used the command line to install it. Which was couple of years ago. No issue since then, until this appears.

Comment: How you run server with `pm2`? `npm start` or `pm2 start joo-app.js`? if use `npm start`, check `package.json - 'main'` field or `'scripts' : {'start' : 'here'}`. in my case, 'start':'/bin/www' occur similar error.

Comment: I run it using pm2 start joo-api and pm2 start joo-app

Comment: It's still does not work. Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: Did you solve this problem @zdrasvutye?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried deleting and reinstalling node_modules ?  Make sure you updated package.json on the server as well.

Comment: Not yet, would it messed up everything though? And which part of package.json I shall update?

Comment: You take the package.json from your local development enviroment and just copy it to the server. Npm does only install packages wich are marked as "dependencies" not "devDependencies". I would try: `rm -r -f node_modules` then `npm i`.

Comment: At last resort you could copy node_modules from local to the server. Then `cd` in the app directory and start with `pm2 start (yourServer.js)`.

Answer (score 0):

**This is for those developing on Windows and then deploying in Linux machines.**

If you deploy on a linux machine and it is suddenly telling you that modules not found everywhere, most likely it is because of the **letter casing of your *require* or *import* statements**.

For instance, if your file name is ErrorModule.js but you accidentally require as "errorModule", e.g.:

```
const ErrorModule = require('../errors/errorModule');
```

this will fail on Linux, because linux is **case sensitive**.
It should be imported as

```
const ErrorModule = require('../errors/ErrorModule');
```

Now, you might be wondering why when you ran on your Windows machine it works; that is because Windows is case-**insensitive**. You can require files with the wrong letter casing on Windows and it will still work. While linux imports are case-**sensitive**.

*I hope this post can help. I was also stuck with a similar problem for a few hours*